# Application that keeps itself on top, and re-launch itself when closed

Tags: android, android-activity, android-service

I need to "lock" a user into an application.  The device's sole purpose is to use this application, and so it is not feasible to allow the user to navigate the device for any other reason.  What is the best way to make sure that the applications `Activity`s are always in the foreground, and if not, launch the main `Activity`?

Now I know this goes against everything about the typical Android application development, but these devices are going to be specifically used for this one application.

What is the best way to determine if any of the applications `Activity`s are in the foreground, and launch one if not?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the best way to make sure that the applications Activitys are always in the foreground, and if not, launch the main Activity?

You don't.

Make your activity be the home screen, and they can't go anywhere. And roll your own firmware, so that the user can't safe-boot the device and remove your home screen.

Comment: Ahh, beat me to the punch, and all I did was reference one of your answers elsewhere. ;P

Comment: Is the home screen solution dependent upon rolling on your own firmware?

Comment: @Styler: That depends upon your definition of "dependent". Without it, knowledgeable users of your device can reboot the device into safe mode, where they will get the device's stock home screen and can, among other things, remove your app. Android is designed to empower the person holding the device -- the only "higher authority" is whoever wrote the firmware.

Comment: @CommonsWare do you have any examples available of this being implemented, or source code?

Comment: There is a sample home screen app in your SDK samples. It's called `Home`.

Answer (score 0):

I will probably use a service which gonna check using a flag as example for a living activity.

Look here for more detail about how to do : http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html

Answer (score 0):

See the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230280/capturing-home-intent-programmatically): basically you must implement a second app that captures home intents and simply re-launches your primary application if it is ever closed.

Answer (score 0):

In reference to what CommonsWare was saying, you could actually partially brick the device. I've done it on accident where I've bricked the recovery menu, but not the actual regular boot. This is a terrible idea of course and should not be used practically.