# IntentFilter not working when created runtime

Tags: android

I have a problem. I need to interupt link that are not static but the user will create list of all at runtime. So I am creating my intentfilter object at runtime. So when i use the code in manifest file it works.But using it in java class doesn't work for me. Here's the code

This is not working

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
             filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
             filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
             filter.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE);
             filter.addDataAuthority("www.facebook.com", null);
             filter.addDataScheme("http");
RecieveBroadcaster  receiver = new RecieveBroadcaster();     
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

But if setting statically it works in manifest

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com"/>
             <data android:scheme="http" android:host="facebook.com"/>

        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2230280/capturing-home-intent-programmatically  this link might be helpfull

Comment: possible duplicate of [interupting link to my app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579447/interupting-link-to-my-app)

Answer (score 0):

In this case, it may just be that your authority doesn't match. In the manifest version, you have android:host="facebook.com" and in the programmatic version, you have addDataAuthority("www.facebook.com", null)

DataAuthority must be an exact match.