# interrupting link to my app

Tags: android

I have a problem. I'm using the below code to interrupt links to my app as

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="twitter.com"/>
    <data android:scheme="http" android:host="facebook.com"/>
</intent-filter>
```

But the problem is that I need to set data scheme and host at runtime i.e. I can add or delete the host at runtime. How to set the value of data scheme and host at runtime? I am using below code but it is not working

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
filter.addAction("android.intent.action.VIEW");
filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.DEFAULT");
filter.addCategory("android.intent.category.BROWSABLE");
filter.addDataScheme("http");
filter.addDataAuthority("www.facebook.com", null);
RecieveBroadcaster  receiver = new RecieveBroadcaster();
registerReceiver(receiver, filter);
```

Comment: I have got the answer of this, so if anybody needs help. ACTION.VIEW is an activity action. Hence we can not register it with a broadcast receiver. Since intent-filter cannot be set at runtime(except in case of broadcast receiver). And broadcast receiver can reiver only broadcast action like android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE. So registering an ACTION>VIEW is not allowedand broadcast reciever will never respond to it.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, the string corresponding to `ACTION_VIEW` is an activity action **by convention**; the fact that you place it into the `intent-filter` element of an `activity` in your manifest, *makes* it an activity action!  The system listens for these on your application's behalf, which is basically why you don't (can't) listen for them yourself.  The `Context.startActivity()` method generates these `Intent`s.

The rules of intent resolution actually determine whether a particular `Intent` matches any `IntentFilter`s.  For activity intents, there may be multiple matches, and that usually displays the "Chooser" interface, so the user can select a target.

There are three `Intent` "streams" that never cross: `startActivity()`, `sendBroadcast()` and `startService()`.  These are all initiated via methods in `Context` and each has a specific target `Activity`, `BroadcastReceiver` and `Service` respectively.

It is a simple matter to set up a `BroadcastReceiver` (not `ReceiveBroadcaster` did you even try that code?) to get the events you are interested in, and then use `Context.startActivity()` with the `Intent` you want.  You can even use a custom action, so you know it was triggered by the receiver, and not the user.

The only question is: is there a broadcast event you can arrange to receive?  There may be a system event you can register for, or you may be able to generate a custom event yourself, via `Context.sendBroadcast()`.

Remember you can inspect the incoming `Intent` your activity was started with, and "forward" the same or a modified `Intent` if it doesn't exactly match what you are looking for.  As you correctly determined, you cannot dynamically alter an activity's set of `IntentFilter`s, so you will have to inspect the host of every request.

Remember you can also register receivers in your manifest as well, and have that implementation called automatically by the system.