# How to capture intent (with action "android.intent.action.VIEW") programatically

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

I am getting following log while previewing a Gmail attachment. I want to receive(sniff) this intent(with action `android.intent.action.VIEW`) programatically. I have created intent filter with `android.intent.action.VIEW` action and I have registered this filter with a broadcast receiver. Still, I am not able to receive broadcasted intent.

How can I achieve it programatically? Help highly appreciated.

```
LogCat:
12-07 18:21:50.528: I/ActivityManager(96): Starting: Intent { dat=content://gmail-ls/messages/hawkagent%40interfaceinfosoft.com/35/attachments/0.1/BEST/false cmp=com.google.android.gm/.ViewAttachmentActivity } from pid 8309

12-07 18:21:52.598: I/ActivityManager(96): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://gmail-ls/messages/hawkagent%40interfaceinfosoft.com/35/attachments/0.1/BEST/false typ=text/plain flg=0x80001 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity } from pid 8309
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you register your Receiver in the AndroidManifest.xml:

```
    <receiver android:name="MyReceiver" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: I have created BroadcatReceiver class inside my Activity class and I have registered it programatically. So no need to register it in AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: VIEW action is sent with startActivity or StartActivityForResult, not with sendBroadcast. it's handled differently: see http://stackoverflow.com/a/9668591