# Detect opening a URL on Android

Tags: android

I open URLs from several different places including through some third party libraries. I'd like to keep track of all the URLs that are getting opened. Is there a way to monitor these URLs so I can log them?

I open the majority of the URLs like this, but I cannot be sure how the 3rd party libs do it.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(URL));
startActivity(intent);
```

Also... Yes, the third party libs do include activities. On iOS I know there's a `UIApplication -openURL:` method that we can watch, just wondering if there's something similar on Android.

Comment: You need to add more info to your questions. It's pretty unclear. Do you use webview, or where are you opening urls??

Comment: are your third party libraries including activities? (in which case you'll have little control over how they do things)

Comment: That's the standard way to do it. However, a browser (or app with an integrated browser) might open an URL without you being able to catch the intent. You could catch any outgoing HTTP traffic, but this requires root permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The action being used for the intents makes it so it looks for an activity, which makes it hard to quietly see the intent. See more details in this nice description here:

[interupting link to my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9579447/interupting-link-to-my-app/9668591#9668591)

You might be able to get some information still if the info you want is in the android logs. You could then read when the android system is firing an intent from there.